# RestSharp baseUrl with a space

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, webapi

I google it and I pass hours try figure how to do it and I can't figure:
I try get Response from web Api with RestSharp v107 in .net 5
Is works well when I do the baseUrl with out space but when I try the one I need with space don't works, I got 404 not found:
Same issue in postman. But when I do in Chrome or in edge with the code encoding (%20) works perfectly the browser return the expected Json

example :
`new Resclient("https://thedomain.name.com/local")` works well
but if I try
`new Resclient("https://thedomain.name.com/my User")` or

```
new Resclient("https://thedomain.name.com/my%20User")
```

I try the with the .AddUrlSegment("elemement", "my%20User" )
or .AddUrlSegment("elemement", "my%20User" )

I think the issue is the url get decode/encode and the space have been remove...

I see we have

```
UseUrlEncoder(Func<string,string>)
```

but I don't how to use it... And if that will solve my issue

Please helps

Thanks in advance

Comment: *don't works* is not adequate as a description of a problem or error. Be specific please

Comment: Does the URL work as expected in a browser? What does the browser convert the URL to?

Comment: I agree that "doesn't work" is not a good explanation of what happens. With regards to adding the URL segment parameter, the docs might help https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#url-segment

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes works well in browser. I try to with postman and same issue I got 404 not found.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I try the url-segement when the string have a space in it his I got 404 not found...

Comment: If it works in a browser but not in postman then there is something about the communication that is different, perhaps cookies, scripting, CORS.. You need to use the browser dev tools to look at exactly what is sent that works and compare to what postman sends that doesn't. Could even be something as innocuous as the UserAgent header. Replicate the browser request exactly(byte identical) into postman and work back from there to find the thing you're missing, that the server considers vital

Comment: You can also make a call to a request bin (https://requestbin.com) with the browser and with Postman/RestSharp to see the difference.